# Retrofit, Gson, Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, json, retrofit, gson

Привет. Столкнулся с данным исключением:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 619 path $.aPoints[0]
```

Возникает при попытке распарсить json вида:

`{"aTrack":{"id_track":52394,"type":"kiting_winter","dt_start":"2016-
12-18 12:19:29","dt_end":"2016-12-18 16:19:26","time":12614,"distance":61609.6,"sp_avg":17.6,"sp_max":53.1,"calories":0,"description":"","access":1,"weight":75,"cardio":0,"hr_max":0,"hr_avg":0,"var_max":0,"var_min":0,"status":0,"u":{"user_id":5153,"login":"iheaven","user_profile_name":"\u0410\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0435\u0439 \u0421\u0442\u0435\u043f\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432","user_profile_last_name":null,"user_profile_first_name":null}},"aWeather":{"wind_speed":1.76,"wind_dir":293,"temp":-3,"humidity":95},"aCardioData":[],"aPhotos":[],"aPoints":[[58.455101,38.158654,114,"2016-12-18 12:21:44",0,2.7,329],[58.455094,38.158667,114,"2016-12-18 12:21:45",0,3.6,148],[58.455071,38.158652,111,"2016-12-18 12:21:49",0,3.6,136],[58.455062,38.15866,111,"2016-12-18 12:21:50",0,5.4,139],[58.455053,38.158681,112,"2016-12-18 12:21:51",0,5.4,133],[58.455044,38.1587,112,"2016-12-18 12:21:52",0,4.5,129],[58.455036,38.158715,111,"2016-12-18 12:21:53",0,4.5,132],[58.455026,38.158804,109,"2016-12-18 12:22:28",0,2.7,132],[58.455025,38.158814,111,"2016-12-18 12:22:29",0,2.7,132],[58.455022,38.158818,109,"2016-12-18 12:22:30",0,2.7,132], ... ,[58.876536,38.19981,116,"2016-12-18 16:16:57",0,3.6,171]],"sLastId":"58568d1c318d40c92c8b62ee"}`

`jsonschema2pojo` мне на `aPoints` выдаёт почему-то `List<List<Float>> aPoints`, хотя в более ранней версии создавал `List<APoints>` следующего содержания:

```
@SerializedName("latitude")
@Expose
private double latitude;
@SerializedName("longitude")
@Expose
private double longitude;
@SerializedName("time")
@Expose
private String time;
@SerializedName("pulse")
@Expose
private int pulse;
@SerializedName("speed")
@Expose
private double speed;
@SerializedName("course")
@Expose
private int course;
```

И это является частью получаемого объекта TrackData:

```
@SerializedName("aTrack")
@Expose
private ATrack aTrack;
@SerializedName("aWeather")
@Expose
private AWeather aWeather;
@SerializedName("aCardioData")
@Expose
private List<Object> aCardioData = null;
@SerializedName("aPhotos")
@Expose
private List<Object> aPhotos = null;
@SerializedName("aPoints")
@Expose
private List<APoint> aPoints = null;
/*
private List<List<Float>> aPoints = null;
 */
@SerializedName("sLastId")
@Expose
private String sLastId;
```

Так вот, в первом случае (раскомментирован) я получаю:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 619 path $.aPoints[0]
```

Во втором, естественно, ошибку при преобразовании строки в `double`.

И не очень понимаю, как из данной проблемы вылезти. Правильное решение, по логике - это `List<APoints>`, но `Gson` упорствует, что ему нужен не лист, а массив.

Получаю я данные через такой запрос: 
`Call<TrackData> getTrack(@QueryMap Map<String, String> map);`

Сломал уже голову, куда копать. Буду признателен за указание направления или помощь.

Comment: Код парсинга gson покажите- `fromJson()`

Comment: квот так: response.body().getAPoints(), получаю List<APoints>

Comment: Пробовали в закоментированом варианте получать лист листов Object? Исходя из предоставленного json должно быть именно так. А дальше вам уже прийдется самому распарсить. По идее на бэкенде поменялась структура данных, так как в вашем json теперь нет ключей, а просто лист значений причем разнотипных что доставит вам массупроблем.

Comment: @ДмитрийК. похоже тяжелый случай или вы не поняли мой комментарий: покажите место где вы парсите JSon строку

Comment: В общем, сейчас добился работы через List<Object[]>, и далее уже получая нужные данные по индексу и приводя их к нужному типу ( (double) obj[i] ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Главная ошибка здесь -- полагаться на глупые генераторы схем вообще. Понятно, что у генератора нет возможности написать преобразование из массива в объект вместо вас. Кроме того, такие генераторы генерируют кучу шума, который попросту не нужен, особенно для Gson. Всё, что нужно сделать в этом случае -- создать свой `TypeAdapter`:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(APoint.class, new TypeAdapter<APoint>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final APoint value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public APoint read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                try {
                    in.beginArray();
                    final float longitude = (float) in.nextDouble();
                    final float latitude = (float) in.nextDouble();
                    final int unknown1 = in.nextInt();
                    final Date unknown2Date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(in.nextString());
                    final int unknown3 = in.nextInt();
                    final float unknown4 = (float) in.nextDouble();
                    final int unknown5 = in.nextInt();
                    in.endArray();
                    return new APoint(longitude, latitude, unknown1, unknown2Date, unknown3, unknown4, unknown5);
                } catch ( final ParseException ex ) {
                    throw new MalformedJsonException(ex);
                }
            }

        })
        .create();
```

Всё, что делается в адаптере: читаются токены один за другим в строгом порядке, с которых потом генерируется `APoint`. Нужно также обратить внимание, что ввиду потоконебезопасности `SimpleDateFormat`, его нужно создавать каждый раз.

```java
final class APoint {

    final float longitude;
    final float latitude;
    final int unknown1;
    final Date unknown2;
    final int unknown3;
    final float unknown4;
    final int unknown5;

    APoint(final float longitude, final float latitude, final int unknown1, final Date unknown2, final int unknown3, final float unknown4, final int unknown5) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.unknown1 = unknown1;
        this.unknown2 = unknown2;
        this.unknown3 = unknown3;
        this.unknown4 = unknown4;
        this.unknown5 = unknown5;
    }

}
```

Пример использования:

```java
try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q658784.class, "response.json") ) {
    final Response response = gson.fromJson(reader, Response.class);
    for ( final APoint p : response.aPoints ) {
        System.out.println(p.longitude + " " + p.latitude + " " + p.unknown2);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

> 58.4551 38.158653 Sun Dec 18 12:21:44 EET 2016
>   58.455093 38.15867 Sun Dec 18 12:21:45 EET 2016
>   58.45507 38.158653 Sun Dec 18 12:21:49 EET 2016
>   58.455063 38.15866 Sun Dec 18 12:21:50 EET 2016
>   58.45505 38.15868 Sun Dec 18 12:21:51 EET 2016
>   58.455044 38.1587 Sun Dec 18 12:21:52 EET 2016
>   58.455036 38.158714 Sun Dec 18 12:21:53 EET 2016
>   58.455025 38.158806 Sun Dec 18 12:22:28 EET 2016
>   58.455025 38.158813 Sun Dec 18 12:22:29 EET 2016
>   58.45502 38.158817 Sun Dec 18 12:22:30 EET 2016
>   58.876537 38.19981 Sun Dec 18 16:16:57 EET 2016

(Если тот сервис упадёт-пропадёт-уйдёт -- на S.O. количество вопросов по Gson сократится по крайней мере вдвое.)